# O365 "Copy Slides to Presentation"

Tags: slidelibrary

Our company migrated from 2010 to O365 recently.

Seems like many links and buttons broke and one of the thing I am struggling with is "Copy Slides to Presentation"

Our users post just 1 slide to this slide library and when someone selects a few of slides and click on "Copy Slides to Presentation" they automatically open up MSPowerPoint with all slides put together.

On our O365, no pop-ups show up and it just Refreshes page (does nothing).

What could be a solution or workaround in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also update your version of Office? I think the last version of Office PowerPoint that support this feature was PowerPoint 2010. If someone still has 2010 installed, test with that version of PowerPoint, and then do the same test with your current version.

See the notes at the end of this article for some ideas: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/11/finding-missing-sharepoint-2013-slide.html

Comment: - Thank you for that! However, I did create a Slide Document page and everything works (new folder, upload) but Copy Slide to Presentation does not work.. just like my company website.

Comment: When I created by using your " _layouts/15/slnew.aspx?FeatureId={0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d}&ListTemplate=2100 " , the copy slide to presentation is greyed out and when I click it, the page refreshed and does nothing. I have PPT 2016

Comment: "I have PPT 2016"  I think that is the issue. Do you have a PC with PPT 2010 installed that you can test with?

Comment: Let me ask my team if anyone of us do have ppt 2010! I will return to you as soon as I get the message! Always thanks for the help Mike!!!

Comment: Just talked to the teams, we cannot get 2010 version and looks like everyones running PP2016. On our old Sharepoint 2010 site, "copy slide to Presentation" worked on PP2016 too, I believe. Is there a way to navigate it to the PP2016 not 2010?!

Comment: As I understand it, Microsoft removed that feature from PPT 2013 and later. Here's Microsoft's info on the feature: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Slide-Libraries-to-share-and-reuse-PowerPoint-slides-C419E77F-8A94-4FC1-A7F0-F5E6CDD7E419

Comment: Got it, so I'll need to tell the users to change their habits and try Co-author! Thank you Mike!

Comment: "change" is part of the cloud! You may want to include a cartoon with your message to your users... do a web image search for "Old man yells at cloud"! (from the Simpsons)

Comment: Will do! Sounds like a great plan!!!